# My libGDX project set up build is failed and throwing an exception. Can anyone help? Here is the error below

Tags: libgdx

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'SetupGame'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6.
  >    Required by:
  >        :SetupGame:unspecified
  >   Could not resolve de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6.
  >   'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/1.12.0/robovm-gradle-plugin-1.12.0.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/1.12.0/robovm-gradle-plugin-1.12.0.pom'.
  >   jcenter.bintray.com
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED